# Instead of running the inner function, jQuery replaces the text with the entire function

Tags: jquery

How do I make it so that jQuery actually runs the inner function instead of just change the `val()` to display the function ?

```
$(".me_signup .name").bind("mouseup keyup", function(){
    $(this).siblings('.message').val(function(index,value) {
      var name = $(this).val().split(' ')[0];
      return value.replace('friend', name);
  });
});
```

I want the end result to be replace the inner text of the word friend with `name`. But instead its just replacing the text with the entire function in my HTML. Any ideas as to why its not running the inner function?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a version of jQuery prior to `1.4`, sending a `function` as an argument to `.val()` is not supported. You would need to do it the long way.

---

**EDIT:** The long way:

```
$(".me_signup .name").bind("mouseup keyup", function(){
    var name = $(this).val().split(' ')[0];
    var $message = $(this).siblings('.message');
    $message.val( $message.val().replace('friend', name) );
});
```

Comment: Ah damn you nailed it! Didn't think of that. That's exactly why. Sheesh, down the long way I go..

Comment: @Trip - FYI, I think you were confusing your `this` references inside the function you were passing. Inside the function, `this` referred to the `.message` element instead of the `.name` input.

Comment: @Trip - Updated with the long version. I assume the `.message` element is an `<input>`. Although I'm not sure you would want to do this on a `keyup` event.

Comment: Thanks so much Patrick! Man I learned more from you in two minutes than I learned from two or three college classes. :D

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to visualize without seeing the html, but it looks like you want to be using .each();  Something along the lines of

```
$(".me_signup .name").bind("mouseup keyup", function(){
    $(this).siblings('.message').each(function(index,value) {
      var name = $(this).val().split(' ')[0];
      $(this).val(name); // I'm not sure what you were trying to do with replace
  });
});
```